# Angular 4 Receive SOAP object and assign to an object

Tags: angular, web-services, soap, angular4-httpclient

I am quite new on Angular 4 and working on a project which receives an object(Sale, Invoiceto) from SOAP API, and push to an object, and assign values from input fields, and send it back to SOAP API.

When the page is loaded it initialises an object from an interface:

```
this.Sale = {} as Sale;
this.Invoiceto = {} as Customer;
this.Deliverto = {} as Customer;
```

then receives Sale object from SOAP API(InitializeSale) and overwrite the object:

```
 this.Sale = response.Sale
```

and it populates Sale.InvoiceNo.

Then I populate Sale object:

```
 this.Sale['Invoiceto'] = this.invoiceto
 this.Sale['Deliverto'] = this.deliverto
```

and send it in the second API call (SaveSale).

On the second API call it returns an error TypeScript Error:

“Unable to get value of the property 'constructor': object is null or undefined”

However, if I assign values in Sale object like:

```
this.Sale = {"InvoiceNo":"1234567", "InvoiceTo":this.invoiceto, "DeliverTo":this.deliverto}
```

It doesn't throw the error and works.

Is there any way to assign all values to this.Sale in one line?

Comment: Is Sale an interface or class? Could you share its code?

Comment: It's an object using interface Sale

Comment: if sale has the interface Customer it should be defined as `this.Sale = {} as Costumer;`

Answer (score 0):

Define the Sale interface as:

```
interface Sale {
  InvoiceNo?: string;
  InvoiceTo?: any;
  DeliverTo?: any;
}
```